# HtmlUnitDriver hangs on zul page with javascript enabled?

Tags: java, htmlunit-driver

Product have been developed in ZK framework. Performed a headless testing with HtmlUnitDriver and it got hanged in the login page.

Later i found that it also hanged on getting the same zul pages as well which is available in the internet. (Ex: http://www.jease.org/demo/zul/checkbox.zul)

```
    HtmlUnitDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
    driver.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
    driver.get("http://www.jease.org/demo/zul/checkbox.zul");
```

Could you please help me with your suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO, I would suggest posting the zul code and removing links to your product, *as is* your question might be some kind of product promotion..

Comment: I tested with latest version, and it doesn't hang. What version do you use?

Comment: Selenium Html Unit jar 2.3.0 version